# Is it possible to add comments to eclipse.ini file

Tags: eclipse, ini

I wanted to comment some custom parameters I am using now, to remember why they are there the next time I edit it.

But I cannot find any reference to comments in this file. Only [this](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&goto=552212&S=9d6e35984a06e2b1e8bb02facbb36a6e), but it is pretty old and hopefully there is a way to add comments now.

Somebody knows?

Comment: it is not the best solution, but what about saving a backup of eclipse.ini into a txt file, let's say,  and comment that one. I don't really think you can comment the ini file

Comment: I cannot edit my previous comment.
Update: on Wikipedia it is said that ini files on windows comments are made using semicolons (;)

Comment: Rather late comment, but I ran into the same question and seems only # works for me on Linux. Semicolons cause error.

Comment: On Windows `;` doesn't work. With `#` it's OK.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Comments can be marked with semicolon (`;`) or hash (`#`) (at least on Windows)

Comment: Only # works on Windows 8.1 with Eclipse Luna (RC2).  Also, I found that comments started with # must be on their own eclipse.ini lines - i.e. end of line comments result in Eclipse startup failure.

Comment: As 4e6 noted above, # works on Linux. I tested it with Eclipse Kepler.

Answer (score 8):

**Eclipse 4.5.2** on Windows 7, # is working for me.
but be careful, key - value are in separate line in `eclipse.ini` and you need to comment out key-value in same time. I added a example.

#### Working

```
#-clean
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.100.v20150511-1540.jar
-showlocation
#-vm
#C:/dev/software/jdk1.8.0_121/bin/javaw.exe
-vm
C:/dev/software/jdk1.8.0_131/bin/javaw.exe
```

#### Not working

```
-vm
#C:/dev/software/jdk1.8.0_121/bin/javaw.exe
C:/dev/software/jdk1.8.0_131/bin/javaw.exe
```

Comment: It should be noted that because of this "limitation", one cannot add comments after -vmargs.

Answer (score 1):

A little *precision* on those **comments in `eclipse.ini`**, at least for Windows (7).
Strangely, using a leading "#" can result in **issues with plugins management**.

Here is an example with the uninstallation of one:

```
An error occurred while uninstalling
session context was:(profile=epp.package.java, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Uninstall, operand=[R]com.test.myeclipseplugins 1.2.3 --> [R]com.test.myeclipseplugins 1.2.4, action=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.touchpoint.eclipse.actions.UninstallBundleAction).
java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in scheme name at index 0: %23C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_92/bin/javaw.exe
java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in scheme name at index 0: %23C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_92/bin/javaw.exe
```

This "%23" character unfortunately is your leading "#".
And the only way to avoid the issue seems to just avoid using comments :(

What I do really **not** like in this case, is that **this "#" doesn't prevent Eclipse from launching** (which is the case for other "bad" characters such as ";" or "//"), but **then** makes other features crash with that not so evident stacktrace (when uninstalling a plugin and facing the former stack, would you first think to an issue in `eclipse.ini`?)

Answer (score 0):

Thomas, I'm not convinced by your analysis of the problem you experienced, because you don't show the eclipse.ini file that supposedly caused it.

I too have Windows 7 but no problem with "#" in eclipse.ini. If you look at the source of the EquinoxFwConfigFileParser class, you will find it reads an *.ini file with the Java Properties.load(FileInputStream) method. So since "#" works as a comment signal in a Java properties file, it works as one also in eclipse.ini.

But let's look just at the phenomena. *.ini files occur in many places in an eclipse installation, for example the config.ini file in the configuration subdirectory of the installation directory. It starts like this:

```
#This configuration file was written by: org.eclipse.equinox.internal.frameworkadmin.equinox.EquinoxFwConfigFileParser
#Fri Feb 10 15:57:47 CET 2017
org.eclipse.update.reconcile=false
...
```

It seems unlikely that "#" would work as a comment signal there, but not in eclipse.ini which has the same kind of structure. (We know now that it is just the structure of a Java Properties file.)

Your error message

```
... in scheme name at index 0: %23C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_92/bin/javaw.exe
```

might come from some ini with two lines such as the following, that can appear in an eclipse.ini:

```
-vm
#C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_92/bin/javaw.exe
```

"#" is a legal character in Windows file/directory names. The line following "-vm" is expected to be a file name, or rather a URI. If the specified javaw.exe is not found, the eclipse launcher will take one it finds in the PATH environment variable.

This for example

```
-vm
#Hello
#K:/studevaux/dev_javaver64/jdk8/bin/javaw.exe
-vmargs
```

worked fine to start eclipse - but only, as I realized, because I have a javaw.exe in my system PATH. When I eliminated that, I got an error message:

[Error message: no java.exe found to start eclipse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WmUWL.png)

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu and Linux Mint (Debian based OS) you can add comments with **`#`**

**`;` not working in Ubuntu / Linux Mint.**